# What are the weather minimums in order to take off under IFR conditions?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules, takeoff-minimums

I've heard different answers for what limits if you can take off IFR from an airfield. I've heard that you have to be restricted to the lowest compatible mins on an instrument approach field and I've heard that you can take off if the ceilings are 0' and visibility is 0.

Does anyone know the answer or where I could find the answer to this question? Does this change for the military?

Answer (score 11):

Carlos answer is absolutely correct but there is some more elaboration on what those minimums are if you are not legal to operate 0-0

[Under FAR 91.175](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.175) you will find the departure minimum regulations

> (f) Civil airport takeoff minimums. This paragraph applies to persons
> operating an aircraft under part 121, 125, 129, or 135 of this
> chapter.
>
> 1. Unless otherwise authorized by the FAA, no pilot may takeoff from
>    a civil airport under IFR unless the weather conditions at time of
>    takeoff are at or above the weather minimums for IFR takeoff
>    prescribed for that airport under part 97 of this chapter.
> 2. If takeoff weather minimums are not prescribed under part 97 of
>    this chapter for a particular airport, the following weather minimums
>    apply to takeoffs under IFR:
>
>    (i) For aircraft, other than helicopters, having two engines or less -
>    1 statute mile visibility.
>
>    (ii) For aircraft having more than two engines - 1/2 statute mile
>    visibility.
>
>    (iii) For helicopters - 1/2 statute mile visibility.
> 3. Except as provided in paragraph (f)(4) of this section, no pilot
>    may takeoff under IFR from a civil airport having published obstacle
>    departure procedures (ODPs) under part 97 of this chapter for the
>    takeoff runway to be used, unless the pilot uses such ODPs or an
>    alternative procedure or route assigned by air traffic control.
> 4. Notwithstanding the requirements of paragraph (f)(3) of this
>    section, no pilot may takeoff from an airport under IFR unless:
>
>    (i) For part 121 and part 135 operators, the pilot uses a takeoff
>    obstacle clearance or avoidance procedure that ensures compliance with
>    the applicable airplane performance operating limitations requirements
>    under part 121, subpart I or part 135, subpart I for takeoff at that
>    airport; or
>
>    (ii) For part 129 operators, the pilot uses a takeoff obstacle
>    clearance or avoidance procedure that ensures compliance with the
>    airplane performance operating limitations prescribed by the State of
>    the operator for takeoff at that airport.

If no take off minimums are specified you can use the "standard
minimums" which are [listed here](https://www.pilotmall.com/blogs/news/what-are-your-standard-takeoff-minimums-part-91)

> Unless operating specifications state otherwise, the following
> engine-based minimums apply for aircraft operating under FAR parts
> 121, 125, 129, and 135:
>
> One or two engines: one statute mile of visibility; no ceiling minimum
>
> Three or more engines: one-half statute mile of visibility; no ceiling
> minimum
>
> Helicopters: one-half statute mile of visibility; no ceiling
> minimum

[Takeoff Minimums (and Departure Procedures) are also published by geographic area so you can look them up for any non standard airport.](https://www.thinkaviation.net/standard-takeoff-minimums/#:%7E:text=The%20easiest%20way%20to%20find,from%20executing%20a%20leisurely%20climb.) For example KDXR is stuck in a valley and has some non standard departure minimums.

[image: (source - own image)]

As Carlo also notes, while you can take off in 0-0 its generally a risky proposition at best, here are some considerations as to why I effectively never do it:

- If something goes wrong but Im still capable of flight, I cant get back to the runway as there are no practical 0-0 landing procedures for the aircraft I fly
- If something goes wrong and and Im not capable of flight I have no practical means of picking an emergency landing spot as I will presumably be in IMC immediately
- Obscured low terrain while always a concern becomes an even larger issue
- There are a lot of accelerative forces and pitch changes going on between the start of your takeoff roll and the tower handing you off to departure, this means there are lots of forces acting in lots of directions to disorient you, more so than say a VMC to IMC transition in level flight on a smooth day.
- Low level clouds, fog, and IMC often brings with it other weather concerns, I don't really want to be worrying about picking up icing at 100' AGL?

Comment: Note that OpSpecs generally give air carriers much lower takeoff mins than the standard one (or 1/2 for 3+ engines) mile. Given the necessary lighting & equipment, i.e. High Intensity Runway Lights, centerline markings (day) or centerline lights (night), mins in the ballpark of 500' RVR are possible. When doing that, a takeoff alternate would be necessary, since you generally couldn't return to land with visibility that low.

Answer (score 8):

This is dependent upon the type of flight operation that is being conducted as well as the circumstances. In the USA, commercial flight operations under Part 91, 119, 121 and 135 do not permit departures in zero-zero conditions.  However recreational flights under Part 91 in an appropriately equipped aircraft and with a properly certificated pilot do allow for zero-zero departures.  While there is no legal restriction placed upon upon such a departure, the PIC should carefully perform a risk management analysis of such a proposed departure as there is little room for error or pilot task saturation in the event of an emergency.  This kind of IMC should be an immediate red flag to cancel of reschedule a general aviation flight for better WX, or seek another mode of transit.  Impulsively making those kinds of departures has killed people in the past, similar [this deadly accident, which happened in Bartow, FL on December 24, 2017](https://patch.com/florida/lakeland/ntsb-report-bartow-plane-crash-released), killing 5 people.  The tragedy was, if the pilot had waited a mere two more hours the fog would have lifted and he could have departed in VMC.  Another case were very low instrument conditions combined with pilot hazardous attitudes killed people for no good reason.